# Lost access to my windows 10 partition after Ubuntu update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have a new laptop where Windows 10 was initially installed on the first of two partitions. Then, the second partition was deleted and reinstalled with Ubuntu 14.04.

When starting the PC, GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu.5 offers a couple of options:

```
Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu
Memory test (memtest86+)
Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)
Windows Recovery Environment (loader) (on /dev/sda1)
```

Everything was working fine today, until I had Ubuntu install updates. When I tried to reboot later and select the Windows options, it would boot to Ubuntu. I can't access Windows 10 anymore.

How can I recover access to it? I know I have not deleted my windows partition.

Comment: I had the reverse issue. I could access Ubuntu, but not Windows.

Comment: Yes, but the remedy is the same; hence why I flagged it as a duplicate.

Comment: @David Foerster the reverse issue is not necessarily the same. For me after updating ubuntu the windows partitions (boot + c drive) disappeared alltogether

Comment: @DomTomCat: Consider the last statement of the question: “I know I have not deleted my windows partition.” Also consider OP's own, accepted answer. Your case is fundamentally different (despite the same superficial symptoms) and warrants a completely different solution.

Comment: @David Foerster Yes you're right. It's just that I didn't delete any partition on purpose either. And it turned out it actually got deleted. For me the "Partition scanner and disk recovery tool" did help in the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by following instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

My ***hunch*** is that your problem was caused by Boot Repair. Under some circumstances, Boot Repair will back up the Windows boot loader to a non-standard name and put a copy of GRUB in the Windows boot loader's place. Boot Repair does this to overcome bugs in some EFIs. It's an ugly workaround to, but not really a fix for, those bugs.

What I think may have happened is that you applied that fix in the past, but when the regular Ubuntu update came around, it replaced the changes made by Boot Repair with a more standard configuration. The regular Ubuntu update didn't recognize the Boot Repair changes and so created an entry for "Windows" that pointed to the regular Windows filename -- which was really just the old copy of GRUB installed by Boot Repair. This would result in exactly the symptoms you describe. Re-running Boot Repair reset things to the way Boot Repair liked.

If I'm right about this, then you're likely to run into this problem repeatedly in the future. You may want to check your boot loader files. From Ubuntu, the Windows boot loader is `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`. If there's another file in the same location with a similar name (I believe Boot Repair uses `bkpbootmgfw.efi`), then that's evidence that my hypothesis is correct. If so, you might try undoing Boot Repair's workaround. There's an option for this on the Advanced menu of Boot Repair. It's called something like "restore backed-up boot loader files" (I don't recall the exact term). OTOH, if you do this and your firmware is defective, then you'll end up with a system that won't boot Ubuntu. If so, your best solution is to return the computer to the store for a refund, since the machine is defective. If you're outside of the return period, write to the manufacturer and demand a repaired firmware. You won't get it, but there's a slim chance that the complaint will help set some wheels into motion that will result in fixes at some point in the future.